# PHP MYSQL table loop displaying 2 tables instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, web-applications

I have a table on one page "view-truck-check.php" that displays the past vehicle checks that were completed on a specific date. In the same row that lists the submission date is also a view button that will pull up another page "view-submitted-check.php" that shows a table with ONLY the checks that were completed on the date listed on the first page table.

[This is the 1st page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6OfX.png)
This is the first table ("view-truck-check.php") That displays the previously submitted checks and what dates they were completed on.

This is the code for that table

```
<?php>
$checkssql = " SELECT * FROM $appname2 GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC";
$checksqry = mysqli_query($conn, $checkssql);
<?>

<form name="submittedchecks" id="submittedchecks" method="POST" action="view-submitted-check.php">
   <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">   
      <table class="table" >
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Submitted By</th>
         </tr>
         </thead>
      <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
         <?php while ($checks = mysqli_fetch_array($checksqry)) {{
         echo '<input type=hidden name="checkid[]" value='. $checks['date']. '>';
         echo '<input type="text" name="appname" id="appname" readonly value="'.$appname2.'" hidden="hidden">';
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td style="width: 20%"> <input type="text" value="'.$checks['date'].'" name="date[]" style="border: none" readonly></td>';
         echo '<td>'.$checks['submitted_by'].'</td>';
         echo "<td> <button class='btn btn-info' type='submit' name='submitview' id='submitview'>View</button> </td> " ;}
         echo'</tr>'; }?>
      </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

When I click on view, it shows every single check ever completed, rather than ONLY the date listed. I only want to see the checks that were completed on the date listed and only those.

[This is what my current code is doing. Its showing all checks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw1yw.png)

This is the code for the 2nd page "view-submitted-check.php"

```
<div class="card" style="width: 85%;">
<h5 class="card-header"></h5>
   <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">

   <?php 
   $appname = $_POST['appname'];
   if (!$appname == ($appname)) {
   die("Invalid app name!");
   }

   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM $appname WHERE date = ? ORDER BY id");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $date);
        
   foreach ($_POST['date'] as $date){ 
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $viewresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   ?>

   <table class="table" >
      <h3><?php echo $date?></h3>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Check Name</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Comment</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
         <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
         <?php while ($checkview = mysqli_fetch_array($viewresult)) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>' .$checkview['check_name']. '</td>';
         if($checkview['status']=='Pass'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-success'>Pass</label> </td> " ;} 
         elseif($checkview['status']=='Warning'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-warning'>Warning</label> </td> " ;}
         elseif($checkview['status']=='Fail'){  echo "<td> <label class='btn rounded-pill btn-danger'>Fail</label> </td> " ;}
         echo '<td>' .$checkview['comment']. '</td>';
         echo'</tr>';
         }
         ?>
         </tbody>
   </table>
   <?php
   }?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `if (!$appname == ($appname)) {`? Do you understand what you are doing? Please take some care first to tidy up your code and apply all suggestions from the previous question and then you can ask a different question. Please make sure that the question is specific.